# Hash Map with LinkedList in java

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

Is there a built in implementation in java for hash map whose values are linked lists?

like, if I put:

```
 map.put(1, "A");
 map.put(1, "B");
```

then it automatically add A and B to the linked list. When I retrieve from the map, as:

```
  map.get(1)
```

I get back a list containing both of them?

Answer (score 4):

Java does not have it but you can use [MultiMap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

> A collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values with a single key. If you call put(K, V) twice, with the same key but different values, the multimap contains mappings from the key to both values.
>
> The methods get(K), keySet(), keys(), values(), entries(), and asMap() return collections that are views of the multimap

This article [Multimaps - Google Guava](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.in/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html) gives you complete idea about how to use it and also how to do it with `HashMap` using `List` as value.

Answer (score 2):

Second put will overwrite first put. You will get B as response.

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced

If you want to keep both entries, you need to use thrid party library google guava [MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, just build your own.

First you take a HashMap, if the key does not exist you put the linkedList in...

Simple...