# Multimap with linked list in java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, multimap

Is there a built-in library or some other libraries which do the following hashmap implementation?

Let's suppose we want to add the following sets to be inserted as

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 5
1 2 4
2 3
```

I found if I had to go to just one level, I could use Multimap given in [Multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201898/hash-map-with-linkedlist-in-java).

However, my requirement is as,

if I put using map, it should be something like,

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
       -> 4
  -> 3 -> 5
2 -> 3
```

So, if I have the key 1, it should put the next that comes with 1 into the same key value and then add 2 into the next level.

Is there implementation like this in java?

Comment: Why map and why not graph?

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a trie or a graph (depending on your needs).  https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706 or https://github.com/brianfromoregon/trie

Comment: I was hoping if I could reduce the computation time to read. I need to repetitively read from the this map and check if it is there or not.

Comment: what application are you applying this to? and why doesn't a simpler approach work, such as a list of sets? From my experience, it's usually better to keep things like I/O simple if possible

Comment: I implemented this with just arraylist and with binary search.....I am trying to find the possibility of whether I could reduce the computation time by applying the hashmap approach. Thank you...I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Is implementation of multimap deprecated?

Comment: Guava now includes a [graph](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained) data structure; perhaps that can help?